# SQL Server connection issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection, diff

I am learning from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx, my question is what is the differences between "Connections per client" and "user connection"?

Comment: I feel I am short of and interested in some basic internals of SQL Server. It is not a problem, but I am always confused when people say terms like "user connection" and "connection per client", so I want to find out why. Thanks!

Comment: For ServerFault, I think it deals more with server configuration and maintenance, but this question is more related to developers. Let me know if you feel any issues.

Answer (score 2):

User connections here is the maximum number of connections that can be made to the server. Connections per client, which I don't believe is configurable, is how many connections an individual client can make.

Here's where there's a difference: a server is configured to allow 200 connections (I'm picking an arbitrary number). The connections per client is set to 10. If I have 198 connections already and a particular client has 5 connections, it can add two more. The limit is the user connections maximum of 200. On the other hand, if I have 12 connections already, 2 from a particular client, that client can add 8 more, bringing its total to 10. It can't add an 11th, because the maximum connections per client is limited to 10.

Comment: Thanks! I am confused what do you mean "client"? A machine has a specific IP address? A connection object of ADO.Net or a specific process/thread?